# value was "" blank when refreshing the page manually

Tags: javascript, refresh

I have a problem regarding the maintaining of value when page was refresh.I assign a value into a hidden control using javascript below:

```
function displaytab(tabID) {
   var tabId = document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_tabId"); 
    switch (tabID) {
        case 1:
          tabId.value=1;
          break;
        case 2:
          tabId.value=2;

          break;
        case 3:
          tabId.value=3;

          break;
        default:
         tabId.value=0;

           break;     
     }
```

but when i refresh the page the value was ("") blank. Is there any way how to resolved this issue? or what is the best way to do this?

Comment: You REALLY need to stop using variable names which only differ in their case. `tabID` and `tabId` are EXTREMELY confusing.

Comment: I'm so sorry ThiefMaster,I've got a typo error.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider putting the values you need to store across refreshes into the page anchor (the part of the URL following the `#` sign). You can access this in javascript via the `location.hash` member.

Comment: hi Amber, is there any way to get the value in server side?
i tried this one for eg http://sample.com#1.All I want now is to get the value which is 1 using server side code.

Comment: The anchor/hash value is never seen by the server, so you'd need to submit it some other way (via an AJAX request or a form submission, or loading another page and passing it via a query paramter).

Comment: ok,thank you very much Amber, i think i have to use the location.hash that you've already suggested. then i have call the javascript function on onload event then pass the value as a parameter getting from location.hash. thank very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure displayTab is not called until the DOM is ready.

A easy way would be calling your function in window.onload:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    displayTab(123);
};
```